# music visualization error with gstreamer

Tags: c++, python, linux, audio, gstreamer

hi I am trying to visualize a music file in gstreamer using the following command:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! 
tee name=myT myT. ! queue ! autoaudiosink myT. ! queue ! goom ! 
colorspace ! autovideosink
```

But I get this error : "There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow."

```
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSinkClock
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstDshowVideoSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-dshowvideo: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
..\Source\gstreamer\libs\gst\base\gstbasesink.c(2572): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0/GstDshowVideoSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-dshowvideo:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0
```

Assuming this is something to do with the thread,  I tried the following command:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! tee name=myT 
{ ! queue ! autoaudiosink } { tee. ! queue ! goom ! colorspace ! autovideosink }
```

But then it gives the folloiwng link error:

```
** (gst-launch-0.10:5308): WARNING **: Trying to connect elements that don't share a common ancestor: tee and queue1
0:00:00.125000000  5308   003342F0 ERROR           GST_PIPELINE grammar.tab.c:656:gst_parse_perform_link: could not link tee to queue1
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link tee to queue1
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you an exact answer because i don't have windows installed.

For debugging this use your first pipeline (in linux works). Use parameter -v with gst-launch and put element identity just before autovideosink. This will print buffer information that passes through element identity, look for anything strange.

Also you could try to use directdrawsink instead of autovideosink. Another test that i will do is to generate the audio with audiotestsrc.

Remember that if you find a bug you can open a bug report in gnome bugzilla so GStreamer developers are aware that there is a problem. Even you could fix it yourself and send a patch.

Answer (score 0):

For `There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.` **Error** Try `sync=false` like

```
`gst-launch filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! tee name=myT myT. ! queue ! autoaudiosink myT. ! queue ! goom ! colorspace ! autovideosink sync=false`
```

or you may have to try at both sink ends of the Tee like

```
`gst-launch filesrc location=file.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! tee name=myT myT. ! queue ! autoaudiosink sync=false myT. ! queue ! goom ! colorspace ! autovideosink sync=false`
```

I also observed that if you replace `autovideosink` with `xvimagesink` or `ximagesink` the timestamping problem apparently seems to be solved.